# Switch between View Modes from the URL

Tags: views, 8, navigation, tokens

Under the manage display for the user profile `/admin/config/people/accounts/display`, I have 4 view modes as below:

- Default
- Profile (Machine name: user.profile)
- Company (Machine name: user.company)
- Activities (Machine name: user.activities)

and under each view mode, I have a set of fields.

I also have a menu with below items:

- Profile
- Company
- Activities

Now, I need when a user click on the menu item (**Profile**), to redirect him to the **view mode: Profile** and so on for other menu items.

So basically, the link for the menu item should be something like:

```
/user/1/[view-mode]
```

I was thinking something easy like:

`/user/1#profile` will direct the user of uid=1 to the **view mode: Profile** of his profile page.

`/user/1#company` will direct the user of uid=1 to the **view mode: Company** of his profile page.

`/user/1#activities` will direct the user of uid=1 to the **view mode: Activities** of his profile page.

How to switch between view modes using the url only ?

is that doable!? if no, any alternative way ?

**UPDATE #1 (My requirement)**

Say on the user profile page, I have the below fields (as an example):

- field_1
- field_2
- field_3
- field_4
- field_5
- field_6
- field_7
- field_8
- field_9
- field_10
- field_11
- field_12

And a simple menu with below items:

- Profile
- Company
- Activities

I want when a logged in user click on the menu item:

- **Profile** (to display for him only field_1 -> field_4)
- **Company** (to display for him only field_5 -> field_8)
- **Activities** (to display for him only field_9 -> field_12)

How can I do that ? 
(my javascript knowledge is very very limited)

Comment: You'd have to do it with javascript - the fragment (`#`) is a client-side feature, it doesn't get sent to the server

Comment: Isn't necessary for me to use (#), but switching between view modes **from the URL** is necessary!
Can you please provide a detailed answer on how to achieve it with javascript

thank you

Comment: Sorry but no, broad tutorials like that really don't belong here

Comment: There is a module that does this but I don’t know the name offhand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_page

It will create viewable routes for view modes. Check the examples and readme. They will display on the page the way they are configured to display from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

[Field group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) can create **tab groups** (horizontal and vertical) and **tab elements** *on the same view mode*. Than you are able to access each tab with a hash.  The `ID` of each tab becomes the has anchor (#company etc).

You have to setup the fields in 1 view mode and place them under the appropriate tabs.

Here is a screenshot of how the setup should look.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I am currently using the exact thing what you have described above. However, the idea I don't want when the user access "Company" information to be able to access as well the "Activities" information by a switching of a tab... (It is really a design based specific requirement)

Comment: @ElieMasaad you can't have hash based urls on different pages, but you can decide to hide them with javascript and will be able to see them only with the use of the appropriate tab.  Perhaps your requirement is not clearly explained.

Comment: can you please check my Update #1 to the question